# I cant access my website that I hosted in home "Apache24" from internet

Tags: windows-7, apache-http-server, webserver, phpmyadmin

I have Apache2.4 server in home running MySQL and PHPmyadmin on windows 7 home edition.

Everything work great from inside the network but if I try to access the website from outside "internet" it take so long to loud and at the end "This page isn't working HTTP ERROR 504"

What I have done for now:

- I have public static IP.
- I opened a port "8080" in my router and map it to my Apache server IP and port "80"
- I opened the same port "80" in firewall on the server, and even tried to turn off the firewall.
- I pointed the DNS service to my public IP and point the port too. "DNS service not inside my network from godaddy"
- I tried to access the website by domain name and by IP address doesn't work.
- I checked the port for my network from outside and both "8080" and "80" working.
- I formatted the server and make a new setup and even tried WAMP server the same!
- I called internet provider and asked them if they block some ports for webhosting and they confirm that all ports I use is open.

I'm trying from two weeks, I almost did everything that I can found from internet.

**Any idea how to troubleshoot this! or is there any other options in Apache server I should change to make it work?**

NOTE: When I restart the server sometimes I can access the website from internet but just for a couple of seconds and only text, I checked the access log file and I found IP from outside, but that's only work for a couple of seconds after that if i tried to access it will show me nothing and also no new log will be there"

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/75538/discussion-on-question-by-narzan-q-i-cant-access-my-website-that-i-hosted-in-ho).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Enable apache's error log and see what is going wrong.

Since you can access the website for some seconds from outside and apache shows your client's IP successfully connecting to server, try to move all your files from `htdocs` to another temporarly folder and place an empty `index.html` file there instead.

If this is working then there are some modules concerning PHP been broken.
See your error log to find out which modules have to be fixed.

From your error.log:

```
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'php_curl.dll' (tried: C:\\php\\ext\\php_curl.dll (The specified module could not be found.), C:\\php\\ext\\php_php_curl.dll.dll (The specified module could not be found.)) in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'php_intl.dll' (tried: C:\\php\\ext\\php_intl.dll (The specified module could not be found.), C:\\php\\ext\\php_php_intl.dll.dll (The specified module could not be found.)) in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'php_mysql.dll' (tried: C:\\php\\ext\\php_mysql.dll (The specified module could not be found.), C:\\php\\ext\\php_php_mysql.dll.dll (The specified module could not be found.)) in Unknown on line 0
```

then later:

```
script 'C:/Apache24/htdocs/viewtopic.php' not found or unable to stat
```

So your PHP doesn't seem to work at all.

Comment: That's solve my problem :)